# Cannot Create Default Instance in SSMS 2016

Tags: ssms

I am trying to create a default instance of SSMS to run through a few quick tutorials on my local machine. However, everything I am reading is telling me that this default instance should have been created during the wizard. Welp, I have now installed and uninstalled SSMS 2016 three times and am yet to be prompted by anything other than a simple request to install and a notification that the request is complete.

I have read online that I should use the SQL Server Management 2016 Application to create this instance, but every time I try to open that application I get this wonderful error "Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable".

I have tried running the command referenced in this article to fix the error:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013

But had no luck.

I've also tried to attempt to connect to what might be the default value for the instance:
-localhost
-myip
-(local)
etc..

But when I ran osql -L earlier, it showed no SQL databases on my machine and since my most recent install this command isn't even working.

Comment: What was the problem with Microsoft support tutorial?

Comment: It operated under the assumption that a default instance was created during setup. If it wasn't I was supposed to use SQL Server 2016 Configuration Manager, which gives me a notification error every time I try to open it.

Comment: Open your SQL Server Configuration Manager and check that the service is running. Then try connecting COMPUTER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS where COMPUTER_NAME can be found here https://support.vitalsource.com/hc/en-us/articles/201965227-How-to-locate-your-machine-name

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont create instances with SSMS. SQL Server Management Studio is to query and manage existing instances.

You use the Installation media to create an instance.

Look for the Configuration manager to see what instances you have installed.
[image]

The default instance is always called MSSQLSERVER.

According to the article you linked to, you probably jacked the installation between the 32 and 64 bit versions of SQL Server.

I suggest to use the setup program and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this installation one more time using the setup program. Wish me luck!

Comment: Well I'm successfully connected to my localhost, but my work around required using SQL express. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: SQL Express comes with the exact same SSMS as all other editions of SQL Server. The difference between editions (Express, standard, enterprise) is in the server engine. SSMS is an independent tool provided for any and all editions of the engine.

Comment: I gotcha. Thanks for the clarification!